# Is it ok to Access database inside FlatMapFunction in a Flink App?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am consuming a kafka topic as a datastream and using a FlatMapFunction to process the data. The processing consist of enriching the instances that comes from the stream with more data that a get from database executing a query in other to collect the output but, it feels it is not the best approach.

Reading the docs i know that i can create a DataSet from a database query but i only saw examples for Batch Processing.

Can i perform merge/reduce (or other operation) with a DataStream and a DataSet to accomplish that ?

Can i get any performance improvement using a DataSet instead accessing directly the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various approaches one can take for accomplishing this kind of enrichment with Flink's DataStream API.

(1) If you just want to fetch all the data on a one-time basis, you can use a stateful RichFlatmapFunction that does the query in its open() method.

(2) If you want to do a query for every stream element, then you could do that synchronously in a FlatmapFunction, or look at AsyncIO for a more performant approach.

(3) For best performance while also getting up-to-date values from the external database, look at streaming in the database change stream and doing a streaming join with a CoProcessFunction. Something like http://debezium.io/ could be useful here.